# How to assign variable length to an array in twincat3

Tags: plc, twincat, structured-array, structured-text

I need to change the length of the array dynamically.Right now the code looks like this:

```
VAR
   arrData : ARRAY[1..200] OF INT;
   length  : INT := 200;
END_VAR
```

The size of the array depends on the length variable.Here the value of `length` variable can be changed during runtime using the VISU(gui). So if I change the value of the `length` = 180 then 20 bytes of `arrData` are unused.Is there a way to declare the array as variable length similar to vectors in c++ such that the memory is not assigned during declaration but during runtime.

Edit:
How to deallocate the memory safely?

```
PROGRAM MAIN
VAR
   arrData : POINTER TO INT;
   length : INT := 200; // can be changed at runtime
   bNew : BOOL := TRUE;
   oldLength : INT;  // to hold the old length variable
   isInit : BOOL := FALSE;
END_VAR

IF NOT isInit THEN
   oldLength := length; // initialise only once
   isInit := TRUE;
END_IF

// if length is changed during runtime then delete the array 
IF oldLength <> length THEN
   IF arrData <> 0 THEN
      __DELETE(arrData);
      bNew := TRUE;
   END_IF
   oldLength := length;
END_IF

// during the first run or when the length is changed
IF bNew THEN
   arrData := __NEW(INT,length);
   bNew := FALSE;
END_IF

// deallocate the memory when the MAIN program goes out of scope
// as we are not deleting the array when the length variable is not    
// changed during runtime


END_CASE
```

Answer (score 3):

The way to do it is to use `__NEW` [__NEW in Infosys](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/2529171083.html?id=5409766235804740463)

`pMyPointer := __NEW(INT, length);`

`__NEW` will return a pointer to first element of an array. You can access latter elements by offsetting this pointer.

You can check if `length` was changed by comparing value from this and previous cycle. If so, `__DELETE` the old array and initialize a new one.

Edit:

I think, that you get your error the moment TwinCAT runtime is stopped, as the momory allocated by `__NEW` is not freed at that point.

Your code should be placed not in a Program (`PRG`) but in a Function Block (`FB`). The reason for that is that you need to implement `FB_exit` method (This method is called implicitly when FB instance is destroyed, i.e. when stopping TwinCAT runtime like you do by activating configuration). There is no equivalent method for a `PRG` as far as I know.

To do this:

1. Create a new `FB`, instantiate it and call it in your `MAIN` and move your code from `MAIN` to the `FB`
2. Add a `FB_exit` method to this `FB`. Exact naming is crucial
3. In your `FB_exit` method write the following code:

```
IF __ISVALIDREF(arrData) THEN
  __DELETE(arrData);
END_IF
```

This method will be called every time you stop your runtime and free the memory.

Links to Infosys:

- [__ISVALIDREF](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/2529165707.html?id=8190095739921439819) - equal to `pMyPointer <> 0` but more readable
- [FB_exit](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/5094418443.html?id=1003025557592631322)

Comment: I tried your method. If I deallocate the memory using __DELETE by checking if the length has varied then it throws an error **failed to free dynamically allocated memory block at address 0xdeadbeef**. Twincat3 expects to deallocate memory when we exit from MAIN program ie if the MAIN program goes out of scope.How can I do this?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code, I'll see what I can do :)

Comment: @shakingwindow When exactly does the "failed to free dynamically allocated memory block at address 0xdeadbeef" error occur?

Comment: When I click on command active configuration. You can see this video : [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fo8CT5HZkjw)

Comment: @shakingwindow edited my answer. Also - I already wrote this comment few hours ago and it got deleted for some reason

Comment: I could not move the code from MAIN to FB as I have VAR_RETAIN variables and twincat3 throws an error if I move the code as VAR_RETAIN can not be defined in FUNCTION BLOCK. And these VAR_RETAIN variables are essential which are used in the other part of the MAIN program. Does MAIN have this kind of MAIN_exit function?

Comment: There is no exit method for programs (PRG) as far as I know. You can still declare your variables in MAIN and inject them to FB instance using VAR_IN_OUT or pointer input. Also - are you sure your spelling is correct? It should be VAR RETAIN, not VAR_RETAIN

Comment: Yeah I meant VAR RETAIN. I solved the error like this. I declared the array as VAR GLOBAL. Then I created function block FB and method FB_exit and inserted the code as you mentioned. So since the array is VAR GLOBAL it can be accessed in FB_exit and when MAIN goes out of scope, the method FB_Exit goes out of scope too. Do you recommend this implementation?

Comment: If you'd like my opinion on your code, I'd like to see the code first